# Looping through Columns while Looping through worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract data from Column A in sheet 1 and paste data in Sheet 2. Then loop to Column B in sheet 1 and paste the data into Sheet 3. Continue until there are no more worksheets.

My code loops through the columns and not the worksheets.

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
    WS_Count = 10

    ' Begin the loop.
    For J = 1 To WS_Count
        Sheets("Bob").Select
        For i = 1 To 2
            Cells(10, i).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(J)
            Range("A1:A5").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Next i
    Next J
End Sub
```

Comment: You are copying 2 cells and then pasting in a 5 cell range - you are also pasting over your first `i` loop paste. Can you explain what range should be copied and where specifically the range should be pasted?

Comment: Sorry, those were dummy variables. The range that should be copy is Cells(10, i) from Sheet "Bob". Then it should be pasted in "Sheet  n " Cells(10,i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes `Sheet1` is also `Index 1` in the worksheet collection

This will loop through all sheets (excluding the first sheet) and copy columns in a pattern like so. The pattern will repeat until you have run out of worksheets.

`Sheet1 Column A Row 10` ---> `Sheet2 Range C10`
`Sheet1 Column B Row 10` ---> `Sheet3 Range C10`
`Sheet1 Column C Row 10` ---> `Sheet4 Range C10`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Strange_Loop()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Cells(10, 3).Value = ws.Cells(10, i -1).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

To loop worksheets try:

```
Sub LoopWs()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Enter code
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simpler approach:

```
 Sub CopyColumnA()

 Dim a As Integer

 For a = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(a - 1).Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(a).Columns(1)
 Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: The copy sheet is static

Comment: After that is updated, the only difference really between our solutions is a value transfer or copy/paste